# Read, and remove, X number of lines from big text file in PHP

Tags: php, file

There are a lot of different scenarios that are similar (replace text in file, read specific lines etc) but I have not found a good solution to what I want to do:

Messages (strings) are normally sent to a queue. If the server that handles the queue is down the messages are saved to a file. One message per line.
When the server is up again I want to start sending the messages to the server. The file with messages could be "big" so I do not want to read the entire file into memory. I also only want to send a message once, so the file need to reflect if a message has been sent(in other words: don't get 100 lines and then PHP timeout after 95 so the next time the same thing will happen again).

**What I basically need is to read one line from a big text file and then delete that line when it has been processed by my script, without constantly reading/writing the whole file.**

I have seen different solutions (fread, SplFileObject etc) that can read a line from a file without reading the entire file (into memory) but I have not seen a good way to delete the line that was just read without going through the entire file and saving it again.
I'm guessing that it can be done since the thing that needs to be done is to remove x bytes from the beginning or the end of the file, depending where you read the lines from.

To be clear: I do not think it's a good solution to read the first line from the file, use it, and then read all the other lines just to write them to a tmp-file and then from there to the original file. Read/write 100000 lines just to get one line.

The problem can be fixed in other ways, like creating a number of smaller files so they can be read/written without to much performance problems, but I would like to know if anyone has a solution to the exact problem.

**Update:**
Since it can't be done did I end up using Sqlite.

Comment: It is not possible to remove a line from a text file without writing it again.

Comment: What you could do is that: you once transfer the whole file into some a simple database table. Then you have a data structure that _does_ allow to delete single lines. If you have a MySQL server at hand, then that is perfect. If not you can use `sqlite`, a simple file based database engine, but actually I am not certain if _that_ does not require to read the whole file...

Comment: Like you said at the end of your question, you could handle the problem with other solutions, like store the queue in DB or store each message in its own file that can easily be deleted after traitment, ... It could also save you from other potential problems ( for example the big file could be corrupted meaning you loose all the messages in queue).